# Laravel ajax form 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to validate and submit a form from a site made with Laravel 5.2
The problem comes, when i try to submit the form without filling all required fields. The StoreRequest checks which fields are required and returns me the errors like that:

```
{"name":["The name field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"subject":["The subject field is required."],"content":["The content field is required."]}
```

Here is how i submit the form and how i want to display the errors of the validation:

```
$("#contact_form").submit(function() {
        $.post("{{ url('contact/store/')}}", {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
        function(data) {
            if(data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
                });

                $( "<ul/>", {
                    "class": "my-new-list",
                    html: items.join( "" )
                }).appendTo("#errors");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: And what would be the problem?

Comment: When i submit the form i get 422 Unprocessable Entity and i cannot display the error messages to the user

Comment: You are not sending any form data, just the token. And `val` is an array.

Comment: That's true, but the i get the same error when i send empty data

Answer (score 0):

422 is an unprocessable entity is Laravel's request validation telling you that something is missing.

Your ajax request is only sending the CSRF token and the response is telling you that: name, subject and content are required fields.

Add this to your form in HTML `{!! csrf_field() !!}` if you haven't already added that. It is much more effective to put your action as in the form, this way you can use form statically and it also means you don't have to put Blade inside javascript.

Form Example:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="{{ url('contact/store') }}" method="post">

    <!-- Form stuff -->

    {!! csrf_field() !!}
</form>
```

JS Example:

```
$("#contact_form").submit(function() {
    $.post(
       $(this).attr('action'), 
       $(this).serializeArray(),
       function(data) {
        if(data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
            });

            $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
            }).appendTo("#errors");
        }
    });
});
```